# QUICKSORT Not giving sorted array

Tags: java, quicksort, object-oriented-analysis

The Output: ATXZK (Not Sorted) Why?
There are no bugs in it. I can not figure it out.
Is there any problem with the method qs(items, left, right)
It works fine with input: d x a r p j i

```
class Quicksort{

static void qsort(char items[]) {
    qs(items, 0, items.length - 1);
}

private static void qs(char items[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, j;
    char x, y;

    i = left; j = right;
    x = items[(left + right)/2];

    do {
        while((items[i] < x) && (i < right)) i++;
        while((x < items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;

        if(i <= j) {
            y = items[i];
            items[i] = items[j];
            items[j] = y;
            i++; j--;
        }
    } while(i <= j);

    if(left < j) qs(items, left, j);
    if(i > right) qs(items, i, right);


}
```

}

Comment: I think the guard close for the second recursion step (`if(i > right)`) is wrong: `i` can never be greater than `right`. It should probably be `if(i < right)`. Because of this error you never sort the second half of the array.

Comment: Oh! yes you are right Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you reversed your greater/less than sign in your last line of code.

Should be:

Is i (which counts from left to right) less than right: If so, keep sorting.

Currently it is:

Is i (which counts from left to right) GREATER than right (IE, out of bounds). If so, keep quicksorting.

```
if(i < right) qs(items, i, right);
```

At least, this made your fail case work on my machine. :)

Comment: Please do not bump old questions - they show up as "active" on people's feed.  It is clear that the user has already got his answer via a comment.

Comment: Whoops! Company VPN was somehow blocking comments but not questions or answers. My bad.

Comment: Not to worry! Perhaps now you might consider deleting this answer.